# Should a computer science student learn about Programmable Logic Controllers(PLC)?

Tags: computer-science, plc

I want to know that will it be beneficial for a computer science student to take up a course in Basics of Programmable Logic Controllers (PLC) and learn this topic?
I mean will this knowledge be useful in later stages?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did some PLC-programming before even knowing what python was, and unless you are planning to work in industry automation (like assembly lines, pumping facilities, etc.), you probably won't need it right now. I got pretty decent at it with no CS or programming-experience, so if you get proficient in those two, you will most likely learn it very quickly later if you have to.

Answer (score -1):

Study your since and do not study PLC unless you must, or you have a task with it. If you know computer science well, it will not tale much time to switch.

I would study promising languages like JS or GO. You can find a lot of work with these skills, and if you are in a position to program PLC, you can quickly learn it in 1-2 weeks.